# How to bind window close event in vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I need to bind leave page and close/reload window event to prevent data lost.
I resolved the reload window issue but can't 2 others.
Some of my codes are following:

```
<script>
  window.onbeforeunload = popup; // bind reload page event
  function popup() {
    return '';
  }
  export default {
    beforeRouteLeave(to, from, next) {  // bind leave page event
      var result = confirm("Are you sure to leave page? Changes may not be saved.");
      if(result) {
        next();
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Can you please explain more clearly what specifically isn't working and what you're trying to solve?

Comment: Confirm popup is displayed on page reload, but not appears on close browser tab.